# Cannot Locate Resources after Exporting Runnable Jar

Tags: java, jar, resources, export, runnable

I have a Java project that runs fine in Eclipse, but when I export it to a runnable Jar file (with "package required libraries into jar" selected) I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
    der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cib.cad.kernel.cmds.StartGui.doCmd(StartGui.java:94)
    at cib.util.cmd.CmdMgr.doCmd(CmdMgr.java:91)
    at cib.cad.kernel.Kernel.begin(Kernel.java:1058)
    at cib.cad.Stylemaster.main(Stylemaster.java:70)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cib.cad.kernel.Kernel.setPreferredLocation(Kernel.java:2615)
    at cib.cad.view.ErrorMessagePrintStream$MsgThread._showMessageDialog(Err
    orMessagePrintStream.java:303)
    at cib.cad.view.ErrorMessagePrintStream$MsgThread.run(ErrorMessagePrintS
    tream.java:268)
```

And the code at StartGui.doCmd(StartGui.java:94) looks like this:

```
try {
        ClassLoader cl = StartGui.class.getClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.getResource("cib/cad/img/StyleIcon.jpg");      
        Image icon = new ImageIcon(url).getImage();   //<--  Line 94
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
}
```

I am assuming that this null pointer exception is being caused because it cannot locate the icon but I don't fully understand why it will run perfectly perfectly in eclipse.

Thanks in advance kind people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Image icon = new ImageIcon(StartGui.class.getClassLoader()
                           .getResourceAsStream("cib/cad/img/StyleIcon.jpg"))
                           .getImage();
```

Hope this helps.